# How to integrate latest Google play services in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-studio, google-play-services

I am work with android studio with google map integration so i want require `google play services.`

I follow manny **Blog** and **tutorial** for **integration google play services in android studio** but not getting success.

I have latest grandle base android studio with google play services which is download from `Sdk manager->Extras.`

I am edit my **buid.gradle** file with

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'
}
```

As per blogs says but not integrating,I am tied from **last 4-5 days**,Please give me proper solution and guild line.

**Error:**

```
Gradle invocation completed successfully with 1 error(s) in 3 sec
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: I need the error not the count. Include Event Log or Gradle Console Output. BTW I have answered for basic error coming in GPS dependency please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points needs to be taken care while using Google Play Services :

1. You must have Google Repository Installed in your SDK not only Google Play Services in order to use Google Play Services as local repository. You can install it for SDK manager > Extras > Google Repository .

Check this

[Import Google Play Services library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio/21086904#21086904)

This is a bug in Android Studio which is fixed for next release(0.4.3) this is work around till next release.

**Edit :**

Check these for Manifest merging failed

[Manifest Merging Failed: Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184788/manifest-merging-failed-android-studio/21186035#21186035)

[Execution failed for task :appprocessDebugManifest. Manifest merging failed. See console for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146642/execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugmanifest-manifest-merging-failed-see/21146741#21146741)

Comment: Please sync your project with gradle and include the Gradle Console Output.

Comment: ya done getting error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.